# Angular 2 CLI load script based on enviroment

Tags: angular, command-line-interface

I am using angular CLI to build my application. I need to load a script to my application at index.html(root) level with different keys in different environment.

```
...    
<script src="http://myAPI?key=dev"></script> <!-- dev build -->

<script src="http://myAPI?key=prod"></script> <!-- prod build -->

<my-root>Loading...</my-root>
...
```

How could I access CLI environment variable from the index page? Would it be something like this?

`key=<% =env %>`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to load extra script tag in `index.html`. If you need to load external script or css library put them in `angular-cli.json` file. Like this

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "assets/css/font-awesome.min.css",
    "styles.scss"
],
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
],
```

And restart your `ng serve`

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but how can I config the environment? For example: I would like to load jquery10.js in dev, but only load jquery11.js in product environment.

Comment: just include what version you want. Before build your application via ng build --prod command, change it in angular-cli.json file.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up modifying `index.ts` adding a line such as:

```js
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + environment.mediaBaseUrl + '/css/bs3-custom-theme.min.css"/>');
```

The problem is that any file will be loaded after the app. In case of CSS, it will lead to [FOUCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content).